# How and what class/file do I modify to insert Cocoa NSButton programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How and what class/file do I modify to insert avCocoa `NSButton` programmatically? (for the Mac not the iPhone)

I have tried the following but it doesn't work: (Request for member "view" in something not a structure or union.)

```
- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *) aController
{
    [super windowControllerDidLoadNib:aController];
    // Add any code here that needs to be executed once the windowController has loaded the document's window.
    NSButton *btn = [NSButton alloc];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
}
```

Comment: You haven't initialized the button. You have called `alloc` but not `initWithFrame:`. You must always call an initializer method on an object after calling `alloc` on its class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add it to the window's content view.

```
- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)aController {
    [super windowControllerDidLoadNib:aController];

    // Get our content view.
    NSView *contentView = aController.window.contentView;

    // Create the rectangle in which to place the button.
    NSRect buttonFrame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 25);
    buttonFrame.origin.x = round((contentView.frame.size.width-buttonFrame.size.width)/2);
    buttonFrame.origin.y = round((contentView.frame.size.height buttonFrame.size.height)/2);

    // Create and add the button.
    NSButton *button = [[[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:buttonFrame] autorelease];
    [button setBezelStyle:NSRoundedBezelStyle];
    [contentView addSubview:button];    
}
```